# How to protect sectors from being written in NTFS

Tags: ntfs, ntfs-mft

I'm trying to implement an anti-forensics tool on an ntfs partition. I need to preserve 1GB (in a precise pysical location) of space from being written by the filesystem.
My ideas:

- Try to create a 1gb file in a specific location (how?) so it will be considered used
- Try to manually edit the MFT and insert a fake entry to mark that zone as used (how?)

Any suggestion about how to implement this two ideas or something else?

Comment: That would be difficult, since: (1) NTFS driver doesn't have any function/IOCTL for that purpose. (2) Hooks are needed within NTFS driver because it decide which cluster number to allocate for a new object (file, folder, stream, etc.). (3) Windows doesn't provide hook mechanism within a file system driver. i.e.: they're either before or after a file system function is executed. In case of hook after execution, actual cluster allocation would have already been made.

Answer (score 0):

Directly editing the MFT is way dangerous. The file system really likes being in charge as it caches things).

You can achieve what you want by using the FSCTL_MOVE_FILE to move whatever portions of the 1Gb file to the location on disk you want.

Note that there is one complication and one problem with this approach. The complication is that you need to move to a spot where there is no file data already, meaning you have to clear the destination first. This means you have to read the bitmap to find out where you want to move it to.  Sounds like a defragger, eh?

Speaking of defraggers, once you've created this file, any defragger that gets run may move it out of it's preferred location.  Just be aware.

Answer (score 0):

This is dangerous and needs some experimentation.

Manually, you can artificially create a file record in the MFT with the *BAAD!* magic number at the start of the record (instead of the *FILE0*), make it's Data attribute non-resident and point to that location in the data run list for the number of clusters you want. Now you have to mark those clusters in the $Bitmap file with 1. You also have to add your clusters to the $BadClus file in the MFT.

The $Bitmap file from the MFT is a structure that has the size of the volume and each bit represents each cluster in the volume from 0 to the size of the volume in clusters. If the bit is 0, the corresponding cluster is free, otherwise it's occupied.

If you can pull this off without Windows thinking the volume is corrupted, that means that you've done everything right from the point of view of the NTFS, Windows Explorer and other Windows API functions that traverse the volume looking for files won't find anything. However, most forensics tools can parse raw volumes on their own and specifically look for these kind of discrepancies. But your files will be protected from writing (unless the drive is reformatted).

Your best bet of fooling some kind of forensic tool is to create a regular file that you can mount as a reparse point or drive but you have to make your own API to encrypt/decrypt that file and mount it as a volume irrelevant of the filesystem it may contain. The tool will see the file but it will be encrypted.